# Replace only the first occurence of multiple whitespace with new line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace only first match using preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729710/replace-only-first-match-using-preg-replace)

I have a string as follows:

```
a     quick brown      fox jumps    over a lazy dog
```

and I want the result to be

```
a
quick brown      fox jumps     over a lazy dog
```

Want to replace only the first occurrence of multiple(more than 1) whitespace with a newline, but leave the other multiple whitespaces after that untouched.

How can I do that with preg_replace?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why? Maybe there is a better way to tackle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', "\n", $string, 1);
```

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), the fourth argument to `preg_replace` is an optional limit, limiting the number of times the pattern should be replaced.

Comment: `\s+` will match a single whitespace character (or more than one).

Comment: @bfrohs nice spotting, updated

Comment: Thanks a alot. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Use the optional fourth parameter, setting the limit of replacements made for the pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace( "/\s{2,}/", PHP_EOL, $str, 1 );
```

Demonstration: http://codepad.org/Kocnyryj

Comment: `\s+` will match one or more whitespace characters (not "more than one").

Comment: @bfrohs Subtle difference, but thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)'s `$limit` to only replace one occurrence.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s\s+/", "\n", $string, 1); // \s\s+ to replace 2 or more
// Where  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, $limit);
```

> **$limit** The max possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

Comment: @AlexLunix, actually, it *wasn't* correct (either were the other answers), but now it is :) (Previously, I had `\s+` which would match `1 or more`, but the OP was requesting `more than 1` *or* `2 or more`.)

Comment: thanks, this also works. Wish I could choose both answers.