# PHP Need to replace 'space' in first word of string

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a php string that outputs like this:

```
San Jose, California
```

I need the php string to output like this:

```
SanJose, Caliornia
```

I've been playing around with str_replace but not having much luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the whole string a CSV? Are the values meant to be handled individually?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729710/replace-only-first-match-using-preg-replace

Answer (score 1):

Update:
first explode with

```
$string = explode(",",$string);
```

then do for all value of $string ( in foreach for example )

For just spaces, use str_replace:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For all whitespace, use preg_replace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

look at here
[How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not very nice, but you can `explode` and then concatenate:

```
$your_string="San Jose, California";
$arr = explode(" ", $your_string);
$result = $arr[0] . $arr[1] . " " . $arr[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `substr_replace`

```
$str = "San Jose, California" ;
echo substr_replace($str, '', strpos($str, " "), 1);
```

Output

```
SanJose, California
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the string is a CSV, you could explode it, process each value, and then implode it.

### Example:

```
$string = "San Jose, California";
$values = explode(",", $string);
foreach($values as &$value)
{
    $value = str_replace(" ", "", $value);
}

$output = implode(", ", $values);
```

*untested

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regulars expressions, it is overkill (slower).
Use the count parameter of strreplace:

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

From PHP manual:

> **count**
>
> If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

```
$str = "San Jose, California";
$result = str_replace(" ", "", $str, 1);
```

Comment: This is going to produce `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference`. 4th parameter has to be a variable that will be **set** by `str_replace` to number of replacements it performed.