# Highlighting Keyword by replacing it (but only if in p tag)

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, tags

yesterday i was searching about 8 hours for a solution. I was here and on several other platforms. I ve given up. So here is my first question. I have to say "thank you" to this community, because i often found help here in the past. Thanks for that.

Lets say i have the following string coming from the database:

```
<div>
  <img />
  <span>Foo Bar - Keyword</span>
 </div>
 <h2>Keyword - Foo Bar</h2>
 <p>Lorem Ypsum, **Keyword**, Lorem Pysum.</p>
 <h2>Heading - Keyword</h2>
 <p>Lorem Ypsum, **Keyword**, Lorem Pysum.</p>
 ...
```

I now want to replace only the very **first match** of the Keyword with strong or em, but ONLY inside of the paragraphs and only one time, not in the img, or divs and anywhere else, because it ruins my html. What kind of function and what regex do i need to choose?

Comment: DONT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX!!!!!!

Comment: I am not going to use a xml / html parser for this simple replacement which is beeing done only once or twice a day.

Comment: @SaschaGrindau: Why?

Comment: Are you matching on the literal `Keyword` or anything between `**`?

Comment: Based on a slew of incorrect answers... i still say. DONT USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead to put a condition that  match only the  string `Keyword` if it must be followed by a closing paragraph tag(`</p>`).

```
Keyword(?=[^><]*<\/p>)
```

Replacement string:

```
<em>$0</em>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/3)

**Update:**

```
(?:(?!<p>).)*<p>(?:(?!Keyword).)*\KKeyword(?=[^\n]*<\/p>)
```

Replacement string:

```
<em>$0</em>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/14)

Comment: Nice, thanks.
What do i need to change if i only want to replace only the first / or last match, instead of "all"?

Comment: may i provide a solution for last match?

Comment: This selects still more than one. I want it to check all p tags and replace only the very first match in the entire string and not the first match in every p tag. Hope that is clear? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SaschaGrindau post the expected output for the above input.

Comment: This breaks if there's any other tag in the text: http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/10

Comment: Nope, breaks if there is a `<p>` that closes before `Keyword`: http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/12 I would do it like so: http://regex101.com/r/yF8yB6/3

Comment: Breaks if there are new-lines somewhere: http://regex101.com/r/sE4iH3/15 which mine handles: http://regex101.com/r/yF8yB6/7 Nice competition we have going here ;) I would advise you to look into my construct of `(?:[^<]|<(?!\/p))*` as it's a solid way of saying "match anything that isn't `</p`"

Answer (score 0):

This code handles `<p>` before the `Keyword` and such:

```
(<p(?:[^<]|<(?!\/p))*)(Keyword)
```

Replacement:

```
$1<em>$2</em>
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yF8yB6/5)

Be sure to [tell preg_replace() to limit at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6729747/2684660)

Full PHP:

```
$str = '<div>
  <img />
  <span>Foo Bar - Keyword</span>
 </div>
 <h2>Keyword - Foo Bar</h2>
 <p>Lorem Ypsum, **Keyword**, Lorem Pysum.</p>
 <h2>Heading - Keyword</h2>
 <p>Lorem Ypsum, **Keyword**, Lorem Pysum.</p>';

echo preg_replace('/(<p(?:[^<]|<(?!\/p))*)(Keyword)/', '$1<em>$2</em>', $str, 1); // <-- Notice the 1!
```

Comment: Because you added the `g` modifier for global when the OP said he only wanted the first occurrence.

Comment: Really? That's just silly :P But then I would [tell preg_replace to limit at 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6729747/2684660)

Comment: Thats not working for me. I set the limit to 1 and php replaces the whole p up to the match including it.

Comment: Are you sure you included the `$1` in the replacement part before the `<em>` because that should put back the `<p>` you say is removed.

Comment: I got it to work as in regex101.com but its still replacing all matches. I just want it to replace a keyword only for one time and only if within a p tag. We re close but not there where i want it to be.

Comment: Did you see I mentioned you need to give `preg_replace()` the 4th argument `1` so it stops after 1 match? Because it works for me on PhpFiddle.org