# Replace first part of a string only once with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace the first (is|are) in a string to (is not|are not), but ONLY the first part. I want it to skip any other (is|are) it finds in the string. How would I be able to do that?

```
$text = "it is what they are";
$replacedText = preg_replace("~\b(is|are)\b~", "$1 not", $text);
```

**Actual Result:**

it is not what they are not

**Need Result:**

it is not what they are

Comment: You could use the `$limit` from preg_replace. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729710/replace-only-first-match-using-preg-replace

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to say that the parameter is the fourth one, and your name is the fourth bird. Coincidence? I think not.