# Need a regex to catch exact uri string dynamicaly

Tags: php, regex

Did you know if it's possible to catch exact string from uri with a regex ?

For exemple :

```
https://example.com
https://example.com/pizza
```

These two URIs are in the same text but I have to make a preg_replace for https://example.com only.

str_replace does not work here because it necessarily affects the second URI :P

Thanks for your time !

Edit :
It's work with this expression : https://regex101.com/r/K7rgTh/6 But I need to catch inside html tags or not :P

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far and how it fails in solving your problem.

Comment: Lets have a look at this article
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Comment: What comes _after_ the “exact string”? You probably want an expression that demands white space or a word boundary or something like that before and after the URL.

Comment: Exactly @CBroe These URI's are part of a CkEditor and therefore can be in any order with other words

Comment: Try to use this regex `https:\/\/example\.com(?=\s|$)`, know that there is no space after a uri

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use RegEx `https:\/\/example\.com(?=\s|$)`, it will replace only `https://example.com`

Regex Explanation and Demo : https://regex101.com/r/K7rgTh/4
Usage:

```
preg_replace("/https:\/\/example\.com(?=\s|$)/i", "replacement", $text)
```

I think this will solve the problem

Comment: Nice ! But I need it to work inside html or not. Go here https://regex101.com/r/K7rgTh/6 As you can see, https://example.com is marked, but not <p>https://example.com</p>

Comment: change it to `https:\/\/example\.com(?=\s|$|<)`

Comment: This works : ```https:\/\/example\.com(?=\s|$|<|")```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a fourth parameter like this:

```
preg_replace($search, $replace, $subject, 1);
```

This problem was solved on this posting [Replace only first match using preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729710/replace-only-first-match-using-preg-replace).

Comment: I already tried that, the problem is that the text is in a CkEditor, suddenly, the link may not be in first position

Answer (score -1):

you can get your domain with http or https like this :

```
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
            $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
        }
        else{
            $protocol = 'http';
        }
        $url = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```